# Set schema for only one column in BigQuery

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a .csv file that I want to append to my BigQuery dataset/table for which one column is in the format dd.mm.yyyy. As I would like to work with partitioned tables, I need one column to be of the format DATE.

However, I am unsure how to set the schema for just one column. I tried the following:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery as bq

dataset_ref                     = client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref                       = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

job_config                      = bq.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.write_disposition    = bq.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND

job_config.source_format        = bq.SourceFormat.CSV
job_config.field_delimiter      = delimiter
job_config.skip_leading_rows    = 1
job_config.autodetect           = True

job_config.schema_update_options = [
    bq.SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION,
]
job_config.schema = [
    bq.SchemaField('date_col', 'DATE')
]

job = client.load_table_from_file(
    source_file,
    table_ref,
    location="europe-west2",  # Must match the destination dataset location.
    job_config=job_config)  # API request

job.result() # Waits for table load to complete.
```

but it gives the error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data,
>   error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows:
>   1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more
>   details.

When I take out the `.schema` option then it works fine, but then it imports the column as a STRING.

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify only one column in the schema since [all the columns names and types are required when setting it](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#schema_components). On the other hand, date in format `dd.mm.yyyy` can not be parsed as `DATE` when loading into BigQuery, so you have to load it as `STRING`, then parse it after imported into BigQuery. Otherwise, you will have to [change your data format to `YYYY-MM-DD`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#limitations).